# Hold 'em tie with 2 people

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

Player 1 has A 8; Player 2 has A 9.

Community cards are A K 7 4 4.

Does player 2 win with a 9 kicker? Or is the K the kicker for both resulting in a tie?

Answer (score 1):

It's a tie (split pot) since both players' best hands are: A A 4 4 K (Two pairs with a King kicker).

[Texas hold 'em](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_hold_%27em)

> On the showdown, each player plays the best poker hand they can make from the seven cards comprising their two-hole cards and the five community cards.

[List of poker hands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands)